# Trigger one thread from many others

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, synchronization, signals

I'm working on writing my own status bar that comprises many modules (workspaces, clock, open windows, etc) that each run in their own thread. Each of these modules independently waits for an event that they detect (e.g. a minute passing for the clock module) and after which they update their internal value which is meant to be read by the main thread that renders the bar itself. My issue now is how do I let the main thread know that an update has happened and it should wake up and print the new bar? I looked into condition variables but since there are no mutexes to synchronize the main and worker threads together it doesn't seem applicable. If I were doing this in rust I'd use an mpsc channel, have my main thread wait to read from it and have the modules send an empty () message when they're updated to trigger the main thread to reprint the bar. Is there an equivalent like this in c++?

Comment: Way too broad for SO.

Comment: Agreed on too broad. Typically, the architecture one would use is a Readers/Writers one where a thread pumps messages from a queue that others write to. E.g., you main thread waits to be notified that a message is in the queue (via a condition variable or semaphore) and then reads from the queue what it should do next (display, or exit for example)

Comment: Pretty much every GUI framework has a concept of a message or event queue, and would provide a way to post custom messages/events to that queue. Figure out how the framework you use does that (or at the very least, mention that framework).

Comment: This is done using X but I was hoping to be able to simply wake the main thread from any of the module threads. In essence the question is about how to wake one thread from potentially many other threads. I wasn't clear on how to do it with condition variables since they seem to require mutexes and I'd rather not introduce mutexes just to send signals between threads.

Comment: I think that doing this without mutexes is a minefield.  The cost of a mutex and condition variable is a small price to pay for getting it right.

Comment: I saw a different code example using condvars on the internet that seem to fit my use case so I'm just going to go with it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that many threads can easily reference the same condition variable that one thread is waiting on and they can all call notify on it to get the job done.

Comment: Right, but then the data they are sharing must be protected by the mutex associated with the condition variable or you will have race conditions.